# Adding huawei p9 lite in AVD manager

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device

How can I add a Huawei p9 lite as profile to my AVD manager ?
I want to test some issues that I've found on the phone locally on my computer
Do you think if I test on a nexus one it will be the same as the P9 lite ?